# I want to know what is actual IE Conditional Statement to support all old ie as well as latest versions ie

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I am new in web designs. Now i have faced problem for 2 websites in which i am working currently. My template only support in Firefox browser and don't support other main browser as like IE, chrome, Opera, safari.

I have tried some If IE conditional statement it is like

```
 <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->

 <!--[if IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->

 <!--[if IE 8]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->

 <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

but it is not working and i am not sure which is correct.

I found some IE conditional statement to support IE browser here in other posts. But i am totally confused which conditional statement i will use to support not only IE but also all browser.

Any input is most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: If your template supports only Firefox, you should get another template, or another approach. “IE conditionals” work on *old* versions of IE only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**: IE conditional comments are deprecated as of HTML5 and are not supported in IE10 and newer. They're also not a very efficient way of coding websites but if you must use them:

You can use conditional comments in HTML to either add an entirely different stylesheet like so:

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IE.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="regular.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

or to swap out content, or add classes:

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <div class="ie">Hello</div>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]>
   <div>Hello</div>
<![endif]-->
```

to target all versions of IE you can use:

```
<!--[if IE]>
   //code goes here
<![endif]-->
```

to target a specific version (like IE7 for example):

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
   //code goes here
<![endif]-->
```

to target a specific IE version and lower:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
  //code goes here
<![endif]-->
```

to target any browser thats not IE (this will only target browsers NOT ie, it won't tell you if its chrome or safari, etc.):

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
   //code goes here
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: As i have mentioned i am totally new in web designs so can you please explain what i will write //code goes here options and if IE conditional method will also help me for safari, chrome, opera.

Comment: Thanks. I just have another question as you told They're also not a very efficient way of coding websites so what can i do instead of using ie conditional statement. Is there any other way to make website for cross browser compatible?

Comment: well as of IE10 and on its pretty much fine. IE9 is pretty good to, its IE8 and lower that has limited or no support for several CSS techniques. If you are worried about people using IE8,7,6,etc then you can try and find alternatives for things that dont work (theres plenty of help online and on this site with past questions) or if you must you can use conditional comments, just try to make them a last result